# Ruby Need help de-coupling classes

Tags: ruby

I have a Log class that loads in the default logger and adds a few methods so I can have some syntactic sugar; the problem is that the Logger gets the file location and the name `log.progname` from another class that acts as a central location for all information called Info (config options, constants, etc).

It's a problem because I want to make the Log class re-usable. How do I de-couple the Log class from the Info Class without changing behaviour.

My class currently looks like:

```
  class Log
    F = File.open(Info[:logfile], 'a')
    F.sync = true
    @l = Logger.new(F).tap do |log|
      log.progname = Info[:short_name]
    end
    class << self
      def set_level(level)
        @l.level = Logger.const_get level.upcase
      end

      def display(message, level)
        puts message unless level == :fatal
      end

      def []=(level,message)
        case message.class.to_s
          when 'String'
            display message, level
            @l.send level, message
          when 'Array'
            message.each do |line|
              display line, level
              @l.send level, line
            end
          when 'Hash'
            message.each do |level,line|
              display line, level
              @l.send level, line
            end
        else
          raise TypeError, "method expects Hash,String or Array, message was of type #{message.class}"
        end
      end


    end

  end
```

The only way I can think of is to convert this from a singleton to a instanced object that I then pass the values into when I initialize it,
but id rather keep it as a singleton, so any suggestions please?

I guess what I'm really asking for is advice on how to de-couple this class from another and more importantly how to do it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need the Singleton.
Here is what you could do:

```
class MyLogger
  def initialize(info)
    @file = File.open(info[:logfile], 'a')
    @file.sync = true
    @l = Logger.new(F).tap do |log|
      log.progname = info[:short_name]
    end
  end

  # ...
end

Log = MyLogger.new(Info)

# Now you can inject info and even have multiple logs
Log2 = MyLogger.new(Info2)
```

Another nice thing about this is that you can control when the Log is initialised instead of initialising it when the class is loaded which might be a bad thing because you are opening a file.

Comment: So your saying that the only way is to switch to an instanced object?

Comment: I'm not saying it's the only way. But in my opinion it's the best one.

Comment: with this approach you don't loose any benefits you had using singleton and don't have any drawbacks of using Singleton.

Comment: Perhaps but there's only ever going to be one of this object, still I think I'll be using a hybrid solution, I'll just use both, I'll mark this as the correct answer.